# Local System to Lat-Lon

Tags: coordinate-system, geodesy

I have a local system coordinates (Pi) of a satellite and I want to calculate observer latitude and longitude from the local coordinates of the satellite. I did this operation manually, I didn't use any software.

The following image shows the local system and the global system.

[image]

n(unit normal vector) is defined:

[image]

For this purpose I did these steps:

1. I found the zenith angle (alpha) of the satellite in the local system.
2. I applied the transformation matrix to Pi using the zenith angle. Transformation is counter-clockwise direction. I used CCW direction as the positive angle. The result vector Pi_new.

   [image]
3. I thought the result vector Pi_new (finding in 2. entry) orientation is the same as normal vector (n) orientation. So to find the unit normal vector, I divided the

   `Pi-new / |lenght_Pi_new| (normal unit vector is Pi_normal)`

4.To find the latitude and longitude of the observer I use normal vector (n) and Pi_normal.I thought they should be equal.

5. `longitude = arctan(Pi_normal_y,Pi_normal_x)`

   `latitude = arcsin(Pi_normal_z)`

I did all these steps but, when I tested I did not get the true latitude and longitude values.

Where am I doing wrong?

*I get the local system as the left-hand system.

Edit:

The output coordinates should be

```
lat: 40.0023 and lon: 32.9024
```

but my calculation result

```
lat: 27.94597928  and lon :1.31664029
```

There is huge differences.

Also my input (satellite in local system) is

```
[[ 24653272.96068735]
 [-13050866.8145796 ]
 [ -1065587.51414906]]
```

---

Comment: What values did you use as input and what wrong output did you get? Were the intermediate calculations reasonable for the values you put in? Did you check with points that you knew the angles and distances for?

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you firstly. I edited the answers to your questions.

Comment: Do you have any other known values? It seems to me that you need some sort of link between your local and global system, but I don't see any here. Your rotation merely rotates the Pi vector around the local X' axis, it doesn't align it to the normal vector, nor give you its direction in the global system, so unfortunately this won't help you find a latitude and longitude.

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of your satellites in the global coordinate system? That may be a way to solve for unknown latitude / longitude / orientation of the local system, but if I'm not mistaken, you would need at least 3 non-collinear satellites with their coordinates in both system in order to solve the unknowns.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Thank you so much for explanations. I have both global and local coordinates of satellite. As I understand it is not possible to solve this problem with only known local and global vectors and transformation matrices?

Comment: When you say "global vectors", do you mean the vector from M to the satellite? If so, then you can't solve it with just one known satellite.

Comment: @FSimardGIS Yes, global vector is M to satellite. I understand what I should do. Thank you so much.